# Unable to use templates in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, view

I am working with an existing website,(I am new to this site),I have to find and use the `view/transaction_detail` page. How can I do this? How can I find the exact path of the file

Here is my code

```
public function transaction_wallet()
    {
        //echo "Om Success3";
        $customer_id    =   $this->session->userdata('customer_id');
        $customer       =   $this->site->getRowById('customer_information', 'customer_id', $customer_id);
        if($customer->sales_active != 1){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('danger_msg', 'Sorry, You have not active !');
            redirect('customer/customer_dashboard');
        }

        $getWallet          =   $this->site->getRowsByCondition('wallet_transaction', array('customer_id'=>$customer_id), array('id','desc'), 1);
        $wallet_balance     =   !empty($getWallet) ? $getWallet[0]->balance : 0;
        $company_info       =   $this->site->getRowsByCondition('company_information');
        
        $data               =   array(
                                    'title'             =>  'Transaction Wallets',
                                    'customer'          =>  objectToArray($customer),
                                    'customer_id'       =>  $customer_id,
                                    'wallet_balance'    =>  $wallet_balance,
                                    'company_info'      =>  $company_info
                                );

        $content = $this->parser->parse('website/customer/transaction_wallet', $data, true);
        $this->template->full_customer_html_view($content);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but if you are trying to find 'transaction_detail' page look inside view folder, or your code doesn't match the description.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find the file in your project-structure, of which you know the http-path.

- A easy way is to go to the page, view the page source and look for an specific codepart.
- Also, you can look for a word on the page itself which has nothing to do with a framework syntax.

For example you find a header "Tuesday is moneyday" or a class, `"class="moneytable"`.

Go to your project and simply use the search tool of your IDE to find "Tuesday is moneyday" or "moneytable".